# aws s3 ls recursive grep extension '.mov' and total size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I would like to know how to list the files in amazon s3 bucket by recursive way and filter **.mov** files.

Sample output:

sample:

```
filename1.mov1    120mb<br>
filename2.mov2    300mb

Total Object : 2
Total Size: 420mb
```

my current command  below:

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://mybucket/Videos
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`--include` and `--exclude` option is not available for [aws s3 ls](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html)

One option is to grep for `*.mov*` but you will lose the total objects and size info.

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://mybucket/Videos | egrep '*.mov*'
```

Comment: awesome. Thank you.